# How to make a installation file in visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a executable file which I made in visual studio (c#/winforms), and I would like to make an installation file which, when run, places my executable file in a specific directory, for example C:/Program Files and creates a shortcut on the desktop - much like most application you install in windows.

I don't know how to approach this. Couldn't find any guides online either.

Comment: You couldn't find any guides?  I googled "visual studio installer package installation directory" and got plenty of hits.

Comment: There are plenty of references available for this on web. Please do your part and ask for help when you are struck

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Deployment projects are not available from Express editions or from VS 2012.

Comment: Check this out.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/568476/Creating-an-MSI-Package-for-Csharp-Windows-Applica

Answer (score 1):

Add a Visual Studio Installer Setup Project to your solution, and configure it however you want. Reference your other project, and tell it where to put your executable.

[image]